# Delete gap between headrule and headings text

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'd like to delete the white gap between the orange line and the blue box. Also also, is there a "cleaner" way to draw that blue box ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{prussianblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.19, 0.33}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5mm}

\fancyhead[L]{\noindent%
\tikz{
    \draw [fill=prussianblue!80, draw=prussianblue] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0.9);
    \node at (1,0.45) {\bf \color{white} Some text};
}}

\fancyhead[R]{
\tikz{
\node at (0,0) {\color{white} .};
\node at (-0.2,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{lg.png}};
}}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\headrule{\color{orange}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a hammer-sledge like TikZ  to obtain such a header?

Comment: I’m not sure that’s why I asked for a cleaner text. @Bernard

Comment: @Hibou  please have alook at the answer if it suits your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TiKz it would be simpler to draw the line also at the bottom of the rectangle with TiKz --- also using the fit library to draw the rectangle -- I have superimposed on your image for reference purpose only -- please have a look and see if it suits your requirement -- the text and image I think you are already at adding  - now no xpatch is needed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{mwe}

\definecolor{prussianblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.19, 0.33}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5mm}

\fancyhead[L]{\noindent%
\tikz{
    \draw [fill=prussianblue!80, draw=prussianblue] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,0.9);
    \node at (1,0.45) {\bf \color{white} Some text};
}}

\fancyhead[R]{
\tikz{
\node at (0,0) {\color{white} .};
\node at (-0.2,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}};
}}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\headrule{\color{orange}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[fit={(-10,0) (6.5,3)}, inner sep=0pt, draw=prussianblue, fill=prussianblue, thick] (rect) {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, red] (rect.south east)-- (rect.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT in response to OP comment**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\definecolor{prussianblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.19, 0.33}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}

\fancyhead[L]{\noindent%
\tikz{
    \node[fit={(-10,0) (6.5,1)}, inner sep=0pt, draw=prussianblue, 
    fill=prussianblue, thick] (rect) {};;
    \node at ($(rect.west)+(2,0)$) {\bf \color{white} Some text};
    \draw[line width=3pt, red] (rect.south east)-- (rect.south west);
    \node at ($(rect.east)+(-1cm,1mm)$) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example- 
  image}};
}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s what I need but it’s supposed to replace the header and it’s not the case @jsbibra

Comment: @Hibou  please see the edit above to the answer